# How to think about the design and purpose of a REST-api consumed by an Angular.js app

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, architecture

We have a monolith that today acts as both acts as a business engine and serves a web UI. 
The work I'm doing now is to separate the UI responsibility to a new component that will serve an Angular app to browsers. This new component will communicate with the business engine and other components via REST.

So we have an outer REST-api and an inner REST-api. The outer REST takes requests from a UI-client, and serves this by making new requests to the inner REST-api.

The reason for the introduction of the outer REST-api is that the client should only have a single point of contact for communication with the system, thus mitigating security concerns among other things.

My question is if I should design the outer REST-api as a pure proxy that just passes through each request to a structurally equivalent request on the inner REST-api. Or if I should allow the outer REST-api to massage the model returned from the inner REST-api so that it's response is more 1-1 with a viewModel that the Angular app can make use of directly.
So the choice stands between massaging the model on the client side, that is in the Angular.js controller, or in the outer REST-component.
Normally I would go for massaging on the server side to make client side development as streamlined as possible. But that's probably because I am mainly a backend developer and prefer to code there. With the advent of Angular.js and the likes the preferred method may be to pass this concern to the client side?
What is your take?

Comment: Why do you need inner REST-api? Normally one would build a library to share among inner projects/applications in order NOT to duplicate code

Comment: The inner REST-api is partially the preexisting monolith (that exposes its api over different channels REST being one) and other preexisting microservices. So the context is made up of many applications, and the goal is to gradually improve the architecture of the entire business, not replace everything with a set of library.

Answer (score 0):

We have similar problem, say, utilizing Google OAuth to login users.

We always wrap the outer REST APIs through our backend SpringMVC. That is, if we would like to call an API `/google/res` from Google, we wrap it into an internal API `/internal/res`. And the front-end (Angular) always calls `/internal/res`.

A very simple reason is that we have easier control on the user permissions. Also we can massage the APIs the add in more information. For example, we associate a session user to the Google account.

In terms of public APIs, I think it is fine to call outer RESTful services from front-end. But in my opinion, to ensure security, backend processing is always preferred.